# Laravel - Define value using a button

Tags: laravel

*Please take a look at this picture:*

[image]

How can I define the value of my textarea in function of which button I clicked on?

Simple Exemple :

- If click on the Warning Button : My text area = 001 or if it exists My text area = 002
- If click on the Warning Button : My text area = 001.001 or if it exists My text area = 001.002

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as you have mentioned clicking the `Warning Button` in both scenarios but nothing else. It would also be really helpful if you could provide the code you have so far otherwise people will not know how/if they can help i.e. we don't know if you're using vue, react, angular, jquery, vanilla javascript, handlebars, ember, something else entirely, a mixture of the previous or no javascript at all etc.

Comment: I don't mean this in any harsh or critical way but imagine that this was someone else's project and you knew nothing about it apart from what was presented in this question, what information would you want/need to help them? This is the information that you should try and include in your own questions :)